# Temperature sensing bee hive

Tags: sensor, temperature, transmitter, receiver, monitor

I am a honey bee researcher and I want to build a temperature sensing system to monitor the temperature changes in the three dimensional space within the hive body using 5 sensors on each hive frame (25 sensors on the frames), five sensors on each side (20 sensors on the sides), and 5 sensors on the top and bottom of the hive (10 sensors top + bottom). There are 55 sensors in total.
I need to collect the temperature at each sensor as well as the average temperature inside the entire hive. During winter, when the hive can be as cold as -23.3 C, the cluster temperature (~100 bees and the queen) keeps the temperature within the cluster at ~26.7 C. If the cluster breaks, the bees will freeze to death. I want to track their movement through the hive (the cluster is in constant motion).

Several engineering students have attempted to solve this problem to no avail. This project is more than 10 years old.

Essentially, I need to create a grid that will allow me to track the temperature in a 3D space. I will be connecting the sensors to a Raspberry Pi and I will connect the system to a remote transmitter / receiver.

Comment: Desired accuracy? Budget?

Comment: You can definitely do this with some thermocouple wire and a few loggers. The problem is... those loggers are expensive. (and the thermocouple welder is expensive as well)

Comment: I recall seeing a project in NZ 10 yrs ago with hive sound and temp monitoring to detect the hatching of a new Queen. There must be a critical mass of bees to achieve this temp rise relative to heat loss.

Comment: @Daniel: Your "in total" edit appears to be incorrect. I make it 25 (for 5 x 5 frames) + 20 (for 5 x 4 sides) and 10 (5 top + 5 bottom) = 55 sensors.

Comment: just reading about devastating effects in hives from mites and  "nosemosis" infections

Comment: Can you talk about why/how previous attempts have failed? What exactly didn't work the way you needed it to?

Comment: @Martin. Can you edit the question to make clear how many sensors in total?

Comment: It would be smart to test bus capacitance loading , signal integrity with switched layers by SNR to anticipate BER. Then calibrate in an oven

Comment: @Transistor Should be ok now

Comment: Why don't you slice the hive in half and look at it with a thermal camera? I'm sure there is a way you could insulate it and still get the camera measurments

Comment: In 2008, this project was given to engineering grad students. At the time, we connected 96 sensors to copper wire bus. The sensor data fed to an Arduino that was supposed to give actual temperature data. Instead, all we got was bad data. A couple of years later, we gave the project to an PhD Electronics Engineer who gave it to his comp sci students to figure out. They never did. It was too complex for them. When they fed the output from the sensor into the Arduino, all we received was GIGO. 10 years later, this project has fallen on me.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used 1-Wire temperature sensors with a Raspberry Pi to monitor various points on my domestic hot water system. The Pi was running the [OpenHAB](http://openhab.org) home automation system which has protocols figured out for all sorts of devices.

[image]

*Figure 1. The 1-Wire temperature sensor is small, low-cost and simple to network.*

The 1-wire sensors such as the Maxim [DS18B20](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf) are accurate to 0.5°C and report their data digitally over the 1-Wire bus so no calibration is required. Each chip is uniquely addressed so once up and running you have to add them one at a time to the system to figure out which is which.

I was going to advise you to purchase a 1-Wire interface board for the Pi as it sorts out all the low-level stuff and ensured the required timing accuracy independently of the Pi GPIO which may have some timing jitter. A quick search for the interface reveals that the [1-Wire interface is built into the Pi's GPIO 4](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2018/02/enable-1-wire-interface-raspberry-pi/). This may be a new feature in the intervening years since I purchased mine. They seem to have all the utilities you require to sort out the addressing.

Usually networks like this should be daisy-chained from sensor to sensor. The 1-Wire is tolerant of short spurs or branches if the network length is short. This works greatly to your advantage as each frame can be wired to a 3-pin connector for ease of removal / insertion.

Bee careful.

Comment: Pun intended :)

Comment: Tx. I will check this out.

Comment: Also, when shopping for DS18B20, be aware of counterfeits. If they're suspiciously cheap, they're probably fake and may not perform well.

Comment: (*Maxim applications engineer here*) you can buy DS18B20 direct from Maxim at maximintegrated.com, or from digikey / mouser / element14. We don't sell on eBay / Alibaba / Amazon.